# Heroku keeps suspending application

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I recently tried to deploy an Telegram bot which simply uploads files to Google Drive. However, Heroku keeps suspending my application. It does not use services like aria2c which allow torrenting. I don't understand why they keep suspending the bot. Such horrible service and leads to me to favour other cloud providers such as AWS or Google Cloud. If any Heroku representative would like to reach out, I am willing to cooperate.

Comment: are you using free or paid dynos?

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku free tier sends the Web Dyno to sleep (down) after 30 min inactivity (meaning there is no an incoming HTTP request during the 30 min).
If you upgrade to a paying subscription (Hobby is the cheapest one) you won't incur in this behaviour.

Running a Telegram bot on Heroku is actually a good option if you deploy the Webhook mechanism (Telegram pushing the messages to your application): in this case the Heroku Dyno, if it is in sleep mode, will be "woken up" and process the message (Telegram also retains the message for a while before they get processed).

PS: Stackoverflow is not linked or affiliated with Heroku
PS2: Heroku is a fantastic platform (try and use it for a while to experience the features and options of the free tier)